# R shiny: Can runApp() open shiny apps in browser at "http://localhost:port/" instead of "http://127.0.0.1:port/"?

Tags: r, shiny

By default, shiny apps open "http://127.0.0.1:portXYZ/" to run in a new tab of the default browser. Manually typing in "http://localhost:portXYZ/" works equally well to get to the app once it is running, but that isn't the URL string that R pops up automatically.

I've developed a shiny app (launched via `runApp()`) for users in a corporate environment where many users have Internet Explorer 11 set as their default browser. For some reason (group policy security settings?), the current IE11 setup fails to load "http://127.0.0.1:portXYZ" but works fine with "http://localhost:portXYZ". (Either way works fine in other Chrome or Firefox.)

In lieu of asking everyone to use a workaround, is there a way to get shiny to open a "localhost" URL directly?

For example, this R syntax executes fine (but doesn't fulfill my objectives):

```
>library(shiny)
>runExample("01_hello", host = "127.0.0.1")
```

Whereas this R syntax fails with errors (but would fulfill my objectives if it worked):

```
>library(shiny)
>runExample("01_hello", host = "localhost")

Listening on http://localhost:5190
Error in startServer(host, port, handlerManager$createHttpuvApp()) : 
  Failed to create server
```

And The IE11 error message for failing to find 127.0.0.1 is:

```
"Can't reach this page. This website could not be found. Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND"
```

If it helps, my R session info is:

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_1.0.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.2  R6_2.2.2        htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.4.2     pillar_1.2.1    tibble_1.4.2    Rcpp_0.12.16    jsonlite_1.5    digest_0.6.15   xtable_1.8-2   
[11] httpuv_1.3.6.2  mime_0.5        rlang_0.2.0
```

Any suggestions for how to get `runApp()`/`runExample()` to open a "localhost" shiny URL directly?

Comment: I don't know if this would help you, but did you try setting the app locally and sharing using your IP and a given port? Something like: `runApp(host="0.0.0.0",port=1234)` and then share your app within your network using yourIP:5050.